# this.engine.dmmf is not a function Prisma 4.11.0 and Remix 1.14.0

Tags: prisma, remix.run

I've been battling this problem for about 9 hours and counting.

```
this.engine.dmmf is not a function
```

The only thing I've found has been this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/17070). It began after upgrading it from 4.5.0. Here's my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "edge-remix",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "run-s build:*",
    "build:css": "npm run generate:css -- --minify",
    "build:remix": "remix build",
    "build:server": "esbuild --platform=node --format=cjs ./server.ts --outdir=build --bundle",
    "dev": "run-p dev:*",
    "dev:build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run build:server -- --watch",
    "dev:css": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run generate:css -- --watch",
    "dev:remix": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development remix watch",
    "dev:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --inspect --require ./node_modules/dotenv/config --require ./mocks -r tsconfig-paths/register ./build/server.js",
    "_dev_does_not_work:svg": "run-s icons icons:watch",
    "docker": "docker-compose up -d",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "generate:css": "tailwindcss -o ./app/styles/tailwind.css",
    "icons": "npx @svgr/cli  --out-dir  app/assets/generated/icons -- app/assets/images/icons",
    "icons:watch": "npm-watch icons",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "setup": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && prisma db seed",
    "seed": "prisma db seed",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate",
    "prisma:migrate": "prisma migrate dev",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/server.js",
    "start:mocks": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --require ./mocks --require dotenv/config --require tsconfig-paths/register ./build/server.js",
    "test": "vitest",
    "test:e2e:dev": "start-server-and-test dev http://localhost:3000 \"npx cypress open\"",
    "pretest:e2e:run": "npm run build",
    "test:e2e:run": "cross-env PORT=8811 start-server-and-test start:mocks http://localhost:8811 \"npx cypress run\"",
    "typecheck": "tsc -b && tsc -b cypress",
    "validate": "run-p \"test -- --run\" lint typecheck test:e2e:run",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "prettier": {},
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "/node_modules",
    "/build",
    "/public/build",
    "/postgres-data"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.192.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.194.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.192.0",
    "@aws-sdk/util-endpoints": "^3.192.0",
    "@growthbook/growthbook": "^0.21.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.11",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^7.8.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "@remix-run/express": "^1.14.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "^1.14.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^1.14.0",
    "@remix-run/server-runtime": "^1.14.0",
    "@remix-run/vercel": "^1.14.0",
    "@remix-validated-form/with-zod": "^2.0.5",
    "@sentry/remix": "^7.30.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "@vercel/remix-entry-server": "^0.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "daisyui": "^2.31.0",
    "domain-functions": "^1.5.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "http-status-codes-by-hutu": "^0.0.5",
    "i18next": "^21.9.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.5",
    "i18next-fs-backend": "^1.1.5",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.4",
    "immer": "^9.0.16",
    "isbot": "^3.5.3",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "neverthrow": "^5.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-colorful": "^5.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.38.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.6",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-image-crop": "^10.0.8",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "remix-forms": "^1.5.0",
    "remix-i18next": "^4.1.1",
    "remix-params-helper": "^0.4.10",
    "remix-utils": "^3.3.0",
    "remix-validated-form": "^4.6.7",
    "tiny-invariant": "^1.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "vcard-creator": "^0.5.0",
    "webp-converter-browser": "^1.0.3",
    "zod": "^3.20.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.5.0",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^1.14.0",
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "^1.14.0",
    "@svgr/cli": "^6.5.1",
    "@svgr/plugin-jsx": "^6.5.1",
    "@svgr/plugin-prettier": "^6.5.1",
    "@svgr/plugin-svgo": "^6.5.1",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.18.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.4.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/i18next-fs-backend": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/mime-types": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.23.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "c8": "^7.12.0",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "cypress": "^10.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.8",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "happy-dom": "^6.0.4",
    "msw": "^0.47.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.13",
    "prisma": "^4.11.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.13.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.3",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0",
    "vitest": "^0.23.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "org:seed": "ts-node --require tsconfig-paths/register --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"}  prisma/seed.ts",
    "seed": "ts-node --require tsconfig-paths/register --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"}  prisma/seed-organization.ts"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "prisma": "^4.11.0"
  }
}
```

And here's the first part of my `schema.prisma` file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider          = "postgresql"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}
```

remix.config.js

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: "./node_modules/.cache/remix",
  ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*", "**/*.css", "**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  devServerPort: 8002,
  serverBuildTarget:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "node-cjs" : "vercel",
  // When running locally in development mode, we use the built in remix
  // server. This does not understand the vercel lambda module format,
  // so we default back to the standard build output.
  server: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? undefined : "./server.js",
  serverDependenciesToBundle: [/^validator*/],
};
```

Things I've tried:

- Removing node_modules folder.
- Downgrading prisma versions.
- Deleting `yarn.lock`
- I've tried upgrading Remix to version 1.14.0 (Originally 1.13.0).
- Deleting the `build` folder

Remix compiles everything into a server.js file and I can see this function:

```js
 async getDmmf() {
        await this.start();
        let r2 = Ne({ tracingConfig: this.config.tracingConfig }), n2 = await this.engine.dmmf(JSON.stringify({ traceparent: r2 }));
        return fe({ name: "parseDmmf", enabled: this.config.tracingConfig.enabled, internal: true }, () => JSON.parse(n2));
      }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by cloning the repository into a new place.

There seems to be a deep cache somewhere that needed to be invalidated.